# How to get date of one day before in extjs field

Tags: date, extjs

I have the following date field i want to get date of one day before , how can i get that ? 
In my form panel

```
 items: [{
    fieldLabel: 'Start Date',
    name: 'fromdate',
    ref: '../fromdate',
    id: 'fromdate',
    vtype: 'daterange',
    value: new Date(),
    endDateField: 'todate' // id of the end date field
}, {
    fieldLabel: 'End Date',
    name: 'todate',
    id: 'todate',
    vtype: 'daterange',
    value: new Date(),
    startDateField: 'fromdate' // id of the start date field
}]
```

Today I am getting 03/23/2011 but I want 03/22/2011 How I can get 03/22/2011?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
new Date().add(Date.DAY, -1);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, since Date object doesn't have add method. The below answer using Ext.Date.add did work

Answer (score 8):

Speaking ExtJS language, you can use Ext.Date library for manipulation dates. For example:

```
        Ext.Date.add (new Date(),Ext.Date.DAY,1)
```

Depending on your code logic, you can modify the default value of date field by several ways:

1) In the item's value configuration:

```
        {
            ...
            vtype: 'daterange',
            value : Ext.Date.add (new Date(),Ext.Date.DAY,1),
            fromDateField: 'fromdate',
            ...
        }
```

2) During the component's event. Basically, ExtJS containers have initComponent method which is the most first running, but be sure to set your code after callParent() method in order to access items collection. Example:

```
initComponent: function() {
            ...
    this.callParent(arguments);
            this.items.getByKey('fromdate').value = Ext.Date.add (new Date(),Ext.Date.DAY,1);
            ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
```